# Creating a copy of an object in c++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a class SimpleCircle. Its declaration is as follows:

```
class SimpleCircle
{
  public:
SimpleCircle();
SimpleCircle(int rad);
SimpleCircle(const SimpleCircle&);
~SimpleCircle();

   SimpleCircle operator++(int);
}
```

On the definition I use:

```
SimpleCircle SimpleCircle::operator++(int)
{
    SimpleCircle temp(*this);
    ++itsRadius;
    return temp;
}
```

When I am using

> SimpleCircle temp(*this)

, is the copy constructor being called or what ? What is happening there ? I don't have any constructor like

> SimpleCircle(SimpleCircle newCircle)

or something (other than the copy constructor)

Comment: Yes, it's calling the copy constructor.

Comment: `SimpleCircle(const SimpleCircle&);` is your copy constructor and it is the one being called.

Comment: You can determine the program behavior with a debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does indeed call the copy constructor.  While you don't have a `SimpleCircle(SimpleCircle other)` constructor defined you do have `SimpleCircle(const SimpleCircle&)` defined.  The expression `*this` can easily map to that constructor and hence it's what's being executed here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you have a copy constructor: that's what `SimpleCircle(const SimpleCircle&);` is.

It may not take a `SimpleCircle` as an argument, but it takes a constant reference, which is all a copy constructor needs. The `*this` argument returns a pointer to the calling object, which is used by the copy constructor to make `temp`.